# Hide Application

Tags: iphone, ios4

Can i hide third party applications using my application. If user want them to be hidden temporarily.

Thakn you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. There's no way to hide applications at all, much less hide *other* applications. Everything runs in a sandbox which gives you little access to anything outside.

Comment: http://support.apple.com/manuals/en_US/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf is the only Apple-sanctionned way to hide applications.